# Redirect to an html page inside Views Folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

Say that we have `mypage.html` in Views Folder (Assuming an ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application).

How to redirect to `mypage.html` page from an Action ?

Comment: why dont you change your extension to .cshtml and then you call it like you use to? format in html is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to set this up in your routing.

In your routes configuration:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("HtmlRoute","MyCustomUrl","Path/To/Your/mypage.html");
```

MapPageRoute is slightly different than the regular MapRoute method you see in MVC. It is used for routing with Web Forms and will work in conjunction with MVC routing.  This will map to a specific page.  This is in namespace `System.Web.Routing` in `System.Web.dll`

and

In your Controller:

```
return Redirect("MyCustomUrl");
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're not using routing, so here is what you could do at the end of an Action:

```
return Redirect("urlToHtmlPage");
```